# How do I remove Ubisoft Connect (formerly Uplay) from Ubisoft games?

Tags: ubisoft-connect, assassins-creed-unity

I wonder whether anyone has figured out how to patch Ubisoft games so that Ubisoft Connect/Uplay is not launched, given that the launcher is both unnecessary for many players' purposes as well as preventing a lot of players from playing the game.

Sometimes, games offer config files or allow for modifying the launch script to remove e.g. video intros to a game. Is there any similar option that will allow for playing their games without the launcher?
(BTW, I do own a legit copy and am highly frustrated by the launcher.)

Problem is, whenever I start Assassin's Creed Unity, the launcher is transparent.

Comment: Why is the launcher transparent? With your current phrasing that seems like an unrelated problem.

Comment: It's the motivation, the question remains as is. The internet is full of launcher problems, I am looking for a solution that greatly simplifies all this, given a lot of players remain single player all the time, anyway.

Comment: Plus, regarding your edit, the launcher IS hindering some players from actually playing due to various problems (to be found when trying to find solutions), I do not understand why reword to 'discourage' when hindering is actually correct here?

Comment: Because "hindering from" is not correct English. But thank you for the note - is this a more appropriate alternative? Nevertheless, I still don't really understand their connection: when you start up the game, the launcher appears but is invisible?

Comment: yes only the frame is visible. Took me three hours to get that working, and even then the launcher crashes so I cannot play the game. However, I am not seeking solutions to handle this problem, I would prefer really just removing the launcher at all as was commonly done in the past with many other games (e.g. in the MMO area). Thanks for pointing out that 'hindering from' is no correct english, I did not know about that.

Comment: Is that standard behaviour of the 'vanilla' launcher at this point, or because you have already tried tweaking files? I wonder if removing the launcher is something we can help you with from a legal standpoint, since you would be circumventing DRM, let alone if it is possible to begin with (as Fredy31 suggests).

Comment: this is standard behavior via Steamplay/Proton and seems to occur to other players, too. After that, I got it to work with Lutris, but only partially.
But there is no point in the DRM if I legally own the game on Steam, right? DRM removal is perfectly legal only if done for personal usage. I believe the instructions to do so are legal, too, as in theory, you can also give instructions on how to murder, as long as there is no intention and action to perform an illegal activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133065/discussion-between-joachim-and-kaiya).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for your problem, but I would guess Ubisoft games on Uplay are built from the ground up to work with UPlay, probably at least as a form of DRM but also all social features and stuff.

Like I'm pretty sure for any Ubi game that uses matchmaking, the matchmaking goes trough uplay, and would crash if Uplay is not present. Or in Assassins Creed, all their cash shop (even if I personally hate it) goes through Uplay.

I would highly doubt you can simply remove it and the game to still work.

Comment: But I, as many other players, am not using ANY of these features and thus I would be perfectly fine with crashes occuring IF any of those methods were called, given that I, as many other players, would play the game singleplayer only and do not require to track achievements or playtime. I played the previous parts on console and switched to PC because I do not want to have consoles anymore, but sadly this Uplay thing is a great issue in terms of accessibility to the game for all Linux gamers and even many Windows gamers, thus my motivation to ask if anyone succeeded or knows about how to do it

Comment: Even if you are not using the examples I've given, I'm certain at some point early in the game you will encounter something that in NEEDs to check with uplay or it will crash. Maybe it could be fine for games that run 100% offline, but still, I would not be surprised that there is something random that checks the uplay process or something. Thats the kind of thing that if you can't find a patch removing it with a quick google search, that must mean there is something that you hit if you try to develop such a patch that makes it impossible to patch over.

Comment: My guess stems from the fact that information is gold in most things today. Gaming is no different. So they force you to have that thing to act as DRM yes, but also to know how you use their games. And that crap is seemingly so valuable that it must be a thing internally that you make it so the game can't run if the uplay process is not on. I'm way outside of what I know, and except getting someone from ubi to confess we will never know, but that would be my guess.

Comment: but there are drm-free copies on thepiratebay, so someone seems to have found a circumvention. However, the crack is for Windows (and yes, cracking of games you legally bought is legal xD)... ;) Aside from that, I totally agree with your opinion on why they do this. They have very active (but unhelpful) support, so there is no way they are not aware of the problems caused by their launcher :/

Comment: Yeah I would not go into the cracked subject in Arqade, its off limits. I guess the cracked has a way to deal with it and if I'm right, their way might just be to emulate what the hell uplay does when asked. But yeah, as long as nobody has an answer, I'm gonna keep the guess that my answer is right.

Comment: @kaiya the wonders of outsourcing 100% of your employees that talk to people outside the main company. Having support that can do nothing but regurgitate copy pasted messages slightly better than a bot.